# Visual Studio or NPM webpack -> Creating a separate folder with a dot after that can't be removed

Tags: visual-studio, webpack

I don't know if this is the right forum but since it happened while coding I'll try here first.

Folder structure looks like this:

[image]

Example: `Folder` and `Folder.`

I can rename any of the folders to something else. If I do this the other folder with or without the `.` will then have a `.` in the folder name after. Ergo if it was already there the folder name stays the same and if the folder does not have a dot it will now have one.

If I then try to open the folder with the `.` I get the following error:

> Location is not available.
>
> C:\Users\%username%\%Folder Name is
>   unavailable. If the location is on this PC, make sure the device or
>    drive is connected or the disc is inserted and then try again. If the 
>   location is on the network, make sure you ‘re connected to the network or 
>   Internet and then try again. If the location cannot be found, it might have 
>   been moved or 
>   deleted

I can't delete the folder either because I get the error `Could not find this item`.

If I look at the files through `SourceTree` when I have changed folder name it shows up as if the files were moved to the renamed folder. If I choose discard then it shows up as every file has been moved to the `.` folder.

If i check location for the `.` folder it points to the none dot folder.

I can't say when it happened because I have been using both Visual Studio and Webpack developing tonight.

It seems to me like a corrupt file system but I don't know what to do. When I first saw the `.` folder I though I hade made a misclick and copied my original content because the content was the same. However when I removed it I also removed two hours of coding. Luckily I had committed the other code before.

I could see one hidden file through source control but deleting it did not help. What can I do?

```
desktop.ini

[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Documents
```

If I try to create a new folder with a dot in the dot or dots will automatically be removed. Can someone tell me what has happened and how I can restore this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say what happened but here is how I got back:

Found an anser here for how to delete a folder that has a name that ends with a dot (".").

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123173/3850405

```
rd /s "\\?\C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\<Project>\<Folder>."
```

I first tried to run the command through PowerShell but that did not work, I got the following error:

```
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
```

I then tried Command Prompt as `Administrator` and then it worked.