# "This is no longer located in XXXX. Verify the item’s location and try again" error when trying to access file

Tags: windows, command-prompt, filenames

I have "This is no longer located in C:\Users\Karina. Verify the item’s location and try again" error when I try to move/ delete/ open file situated in my "Users" folder. It appeared because I wanted to create `.gitignore` but ended up creating `.gitignore.`  — I didn’t spesified the extension. I tried to rename it with Command Promp by this command:

```
DIR /A /X /P
RENAME (name of the problematic file) (some other name)
EXIT
```

But it says it couldn’t find this item either. I know we can delete a file in Command Promp too but I am a bit afraid to try it out, as it is just a file, not a folder — so when I will type a file location, I will type `C:\Users\Karina`. Won’t it delete my "Karina" folder entirely?

Surprisingly I can open up this `.gitignore.` in my Photoshop. So I wanted to save it after editing it there, just so I can later delete it. But I cannot do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to [delete that file](https://superuser.com/a/742379/141) (or [rename it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090531/6309)), using a CMD opened with elevated privileges:

```
del "\\?\C:\full\path\to\.gitignore."
# or
ren "\\?\C:\full\path\to\.gitignore." "\\?\C:\full\path\to\.gitignore"
```

Then you can see if the move proceeds.

Comment: It says "the system cannot find the path specified", when I try to rename it through CMD

Comment: @Karina Do you see it in the Windows explorer?

Comment: I see it as a response on my command in cmd

Comment: @Karina I understand, but do you still see the `.gitignore.` file? (either in a file explorer, or in your CMD, with a `dir` in the parent folder)

Comment: yes, I still see it in the file explorer too

Comment: @Karina `del "\\?\C:\full\path\to\.gitignore."`: you did replace the `full\path\to` part of the command by the actual full path of that file?

Comment: Yes, of course! Is there any possibility it may really not be located there though I can see it?

Comment: @Karina No, it should be here. Any chance there is a typo, or a space after the file name, as in '`.gitignore. `'?

Comment: So I am writing `\\?\C:\Users\Karina\.gitignore.` — is that correct (considering this is the correct full path where I can see this file)? If so, then no, there is no typos

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me after several searches

```
rd /s \\?\Drive:\bad\folder\path
```

This will delete the folder containing the problematic file